# Design of a low frequency (80 kHz) voltage-controlled oscillator circuit

Tags: rf, oscillator, ltspice, radio, vco

I'm working on a project involving low frequency, through-the-earth data transmission from a transmitter in a karst cave system to a receiver on the surface. I've worked out that a SDR can be used for the receiver but there doesn't seem to be any readily available SDR packages for data **transmission** at around 80 kHz. Because of this I've looked to creating my own VCO circuit. I've produced a draft schematic in LTSPICE XVII that meets the target transmission frequency of around 80 kHz but the transmitting power is a little too high for my liking.

Admittedly, I don't know everything there is to know about how a circuit like this functions so if anyone could guide me through or give me some pointers on how to optimise this circuit for this purpose and potentially drive down the transmitting power then I would greatly appreciate it.

Attached is the VCO circuit in question and an Octave simulation from 1 kHz to 1 GHz, with associated values.

[image]

Comment: Generating the oscillation is very easy to do in software (80 kHz is something that a studio soundcard could still trivially do, all you'd need to give it is a 80 kHz sine sampled at 192 kS/s; any microcontroller would have as easy a time.), you need to build an amplifier, not an oscillator.

Comment: You've forgot to ask a specific question, by the way!

Comment: SDR and just a single frequency from a VCO are two completely different things. If you want a VCO then by far the easiest solution would be to just buy an "off-the-shelf" VCO chip... If on the other hand you want a low-frequency SDR-like solution then as @MarcusMüller mentioned just use an audio device instead, like an audio codac for example.

Comment: My understanding is that a VCO simply modulates an input signal for transmission and that SDR is the whole deal (ADC, detection, demodulation, etc.) managed in software. Am I incorrect in assuming a VCO can be used to transmit a data stream underground to a software-defined receiver on the surface?

Comment: That circuit is an amplifier, not an oscillator.  Do you want an **oscillator**, that delivers an 80kHz sine wave when you apply power, or do you want an **amplifier**, that takes an 80kHz sine wave and makes it bigger or more powerful?

Comment: I want an oscillator that delivers an 80kHz carrier wave that is modulated by an input data stream.

Comment: You needn't worry about this circuit being too *powerful* since your **AC analysis** is an unrealistic extrapolation. Should you double the **input** voltage source amplitude, LTSpice will simply double the output amplitude. A **transient analysis** will show a more realistic output...which you will find is very feeble.

Comment: @K.Millar but you wouldn't modulate a VCO at 80 kHz. You'd directly generate the modulated signal, numerically, on whatever device the data you want to send originates on. Again, you **really** don't need a VCO to generate a carrier.

Comment: *Am I incorrect in assuming a VCO can be used to transmit a data stream underground to a software-defined receiver on the surface?* strictly speaking, you're not wrong. Practically speaking, you don't *need* the VCO, it's just an unnecessary piece of analog hardware if you ask me: it restricts yourself to using frequency shift keying with pretty inaccurate frequencies and hence high error rates, and you still need something like a microcontroller to modulate the voltage for your VCO. That microcontroller can, however, pretty trivially also do the job of your VCO, just better. So, drop the VCO.

Comment: Thanks for the information, it's genuinely helpful. I'm still trying to form an understanding on this topic so forgive me if some of my questions seem silly. The device that's generating the data is a 3rd party measurement instrument using a Raspberry Pi. What exactly do you mean with "directly" generating a modulated signal "numerically"? My knowledge on radio systems is limited, so far, mainly to traditional hardware-based implementation (physical mixing, amplification, ADC, etc.).

Comment: @K.Millar Assuming I'm right and "through-the-earth" means literally using vibrations through rock and dirt, I find no information on the most important thing to me. *What's the transducer?* You mention "transmitting power" being high... But this is earth. The mechanisms used *determine* the better answers, it seems to me. But there's no info about the transducer. Without that, I almost feel as though I'm considering moving deck chairs on the Titanic. The iceberg in the room, though, is the transducer.

Comment: I recall reading in an old HAM magazine about using a 50W stereo amplifier to do earth transmissions aka ground waves.  Ground in this instance is literally the earth! I guess they were doing 10-20kHz based on that type of amp.